# Necesito guardar los mismos datos en una pila y en un vector.

Tags: java, pilas

Cuando mando imprimir el vector me dice : " [I@1540e19d " Ayuda urgente por favor!!! :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n,x,dato,cp=0,cn=0,guardaDato;
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    System.out.println("Introduzcase el tamaño de la pila 1: ");
    n=Keyboard.readInt();
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    System.out.println("El tamaño de la pila 1 es de "+n+" elementos.");
    System.out.println("=======================================");

    PilaG<Integer> pila1 = new PilaG<Integer>(n);
    int []vector= new int [n];

    for ( int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero en la posición "+(i+1));
        dato= sc.nextInt();
        pila1.Push(dato);
    }

    pila1.estado();

    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
            pila1.Pop();
            guardaDato=(int) pila1.dret;
            vector[k]=guardaDato;
    }

    System.out.print(vector);


}
```

}

Comment: Estas tratando de imprimir `vector` de una forma incorrecta. Cambia la última línea por `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(vector));`

Comment: Cuando llamas al vector en un System.out.print estás llamando a su método toString del Object (clase padre de todos) que lo que hace es imprimir el espacio de memoria donde está. Tienes que usar un bucle para imprimir cada elemento al igual que has hecho para almacenarlo

Comment: @RobertGomez ¡Cierto! Lo he olvidado... Rayos, estos proyectos me tienen la cabeza hecha un lío jajaja, un abrazo crack, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Siempre a tu orden hermano, no olvides elegir la Respuesta como Elegida para que otros usuarios puedan encontrar la solución rápido a este tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas tratando de imprimir vector de una forma incorrecta. Cambia la última línea por:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(vector));
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes imprimir el vector usando un bucle

```
   for (int index=0;index<vector.length;index++)
        {
            System.out.println(vector[index]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes imprimir el vector usando un bucle
Para imprimir el contenido de una colección debes recorrer cada posición de este. Lo que te esta saliendo por consola es básicamente la dirección de memoria de la variable, en este caso el vector. si quieres imprimir o hacer cualquier operación con los datos puedes usar un for tradicional o si fuese una coleccion como en este caso son enteros podrias hacer un system.out.println() del vector.

ej For tradicional :

```
    int[] vector = {2,3,4,5,6};

    for (int index=0 ; index < vector.length ; index++){
        System.out.println(vector[index]);
    }
```

Output [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ej: coleccion

```
    List<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<>();
    vector.add(2);
    vector.add(3);
    vector.add(4);

    System.out.print(vector);
```

Output: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dependiendo de para que vas a querer usar tu colección te servirá mas usar uno u otro.